# Office add-in development on local machine?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

Is there a convenient/best-practice way to develop Microsoft Office add-ins locally?

My understanding so far is that the TaskPane is always loaded from a remote URL which makes development and testing quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. When you are developing, you can load the add-in from localhost, so you don't need a remote URL. For example, if you use any of the QuickStarts in the official documentation, you will be using localhost automatically. The same is true if you create an add-in project with Visual Studio or with the Yo Office tool.

Comment: I ran `yeoman` and now I get an error message: `Error: Platform not supported: linux.` However, I was still able to sideload the `manifest.xml` and it loads my content from `localhost` (not the yeoman app, but my existing app). I get an error: `The identity API is not supported for this add-in.`. Is this due to some config in the `manifest.xml`. I have a working `manifest.xml`. I don't really understand where the logical switch is which allows me to use `localhost`.

Comment: I think the error message means that you are trying to use Single Sign-on feature of Office Add-ins but you are developing on a platform that does not support the feature. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/identity-api-requirement-sets

Comment: I see some indications that you may not be familiar with some of the basics of Office Add-in development. May I suggest that you start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/learning-path-beginner

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding so far is that the TaskPane is always loaded from a remote URL

The nature of the web technology consists of two separate sides - a client and a server. The client in your case is any Office application where your add-in is run. And the server is any server (can be locally hosted) where your add-in files reside. You can use any web server for hosting the web add-in. Office applications don't care where your add-in files are resided (on the remote server or local one).

The [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) page provides two possible ways for creating Office web add-in - Visual Studio and Yeoman generator. Visual Studio does everything for you when you launch the add-in for debugging while in case of Yeoman generator you have to know `node`/`npm` basic command line verbs. Both ways have its own pros and cons.

Comment: Does this mean that if I have a web app running on my local server, using office 365 admin, I can deploy this add-in within my company? or is it have to be accessible from public domain and hence I have to use a provider to first deploy the web app and then through add-in?

Comment: If the local web server is accessible to all your company machines the add-in can be running without any problems. If the web server is not reachable the add-in will not be loaded. There is no restrictions on in-house deployments (for example, for testing purposes).